# unable to store date in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to store data into database. if i am using the following code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO rohit(content,tags,uniquefield,required)
        VALUES('$l','$y','$z','$t')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

it is running but when i am adding one more field then it is giving error check mysql syntax

```
$sql="INSERT INTO rohit(content,tags,uniquefield,required,numeric)
        VALUES('$l','$y','$z','$t','$n')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

i have defined all the fields in database. what may be the possible error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numeric` is a reserved word. Place it in tics to escape it:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO rohit(content,tags,uniquefield,required,`numeric`)VALUES('$l','$y','$z','$t','$n')";
```

Comment: Or better still, don't use a reserved word as a column name

Answer (score 1):

because you are trying to add a string value to the **numeric** field and I guess that the type of that columns is not a string, because of the name

Comment: No: `create temporary table foo(bar int);` followed by `insert into foo(bar) values ('42');` works well enough, MySQL will convert the string to number as long as it consists of digits only.